A bipartite $k$-connected graph has a matching of size $k$
I have to show that a bipartite graph $G$ with bipartition $(A,B)$ which is $k$-connected must have a matching of size $k$. I tried using a corollary of Menger's theorem to say that between any two vertices $s,t\in A$ there must be $k$ paths vertex-disjoint except for their ends. If I could pick one edge from each of these paths, I would get my result. However, the corollary doesn't specify that $s$ and $t$ have to be non-adjacent. Also, we may have several paths of length 2, in which case I would not be able to get a matching of size $k$ because all the edges could be adjacent to one of $s$ or $t$.
Is there a better way to do this? Any help would be appreciated!

There's an easy proof using Konigs theorem. You need to show that the minimum vertex cover has size at least $k$, but this is trivial, since any vertex cover is also a vertex cut. There is probably also a better way using some greedy algorithm (naively greedy gives $k/2$) so that you don't need to use Konigs

Every $k-$connected graph with at least $2k$ vertices (check that this is satisfied) contains a cycle of length at least $2k$. Hence we are done.

I could write out proofs of the above to directions if you'd need.

@MathieuRundström yes that'd be very helpful!

I should first note that the claim is false for $k=1$ (in fact for just one graph), as a graph comprised of an isolated vertex is a connected bipartite graph without a matching of size $1$. We assume we have dealt with this edge case from now on.
We give a proof using Menger's theorem, and a shorter proof using König's theorem. You could also give a short proof using Hall's theorem, but I don't include it here. Both our proofs make use of the following fact. If $G$ is a $k$-connected bipartite graph with bipartition $(A, B)$, then both $A$ and $B$ have size at least $k$. In particular, $G$ is a graph on at least $2k$ vertices.

Here's an approach using Menger's theorem. Finding a cycle in $G$ of length at least $2k$ is enough, as any such cycle has a matching of size $k$. Let $C$ be a longest cycle in $G$, and suppose for contradiction $C$ has length at most $2k-1$. Then there exists some vertices not in $C$. Let $S\subseteq V(C)$ be the set of vertices in $C$ with neighbours in $V(G)\backslash V(C)$. By $k$-connectivity, $S$ has size at least $k$. Let $v$ be a vertex outside $C$. The following claim (more generally known as the fan lemma) is a consequence of Menger's theorem.

There are at least $k$ paths between $v$ and $S$, all vertex disjoint except at $v$.

To prove this, consider the graph obtained from $G$ by adding a vertex $u$ adjacent to $S$. Observe that this new graph is $k$-connected, so by Menger's theorem there are $k$ vertex disjoint paths between $v$ and $u$. Truncating these paths by deleting $u$ we obtain the claim.
By the pigeonhole principle, there are two vertices $s, s'$ in $S$ that are adjacent in $C$ and ends of such paths. These paths together with $C$ except for the edge $ss'$ form a cycle, contradicting the maximality of $C$. We conclude $G$ has a cycle of length at least $2k$.

König's theorem states that in a bipartite graph the size of a maximum matching equals the size of a minimum vertex cover. Suppose there exists a vertex cover $Q\subseteq V(G)$ of size $<k$. By definition, every edge has an end in $Q$, so deleting $Q$ from $G$ we obtain an independent set of size at least $k+1>2$, contradicting the $k$-connectedness of $G$. Thus, a minimum vertex cover of $G$ has size at least $k$, and so does a maximum matching.

To use Menger's theorem in the most straightforward way, it helps to begin with the expansion lemma:
Expansion lemma. If $G$ is a $k$-connected graph, and $G'$ is obtained from $G$ by adding a new vertex with at least $k$ neighbors in $G$, then $G'$ is also $k$-connected.
Using this lemma, add a new vertex $s$ adjacent to all vertices of $A$, and a new vertex $t$ adjacent to all vertices of $B$. (For $k > 1$, we must have $|A| \ge k$ and $|B|\ge k$, because deleting all of $A$ or all of $B$ would disconnect the graph.)
The resulting graph must still be $k$-connected, and so there are $k$ internally disjoint $s-t$ paths by Menger's theorem.
Each of those paths contains at least one edge of $G$. If we pick one such edge from each path (for a total of $k$ edges), then the result is a matching, because the paths are internally disjoint.
